# Stateful stream processing with Spark DataFrames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to achieve stateful stream processing with Spark DataFrame API? The first thing I'd like to try is deduplicate the stream. `DStream` has `mapWithState` method, but in order to convert it to DataFrames, I have to use `foreachRDD`:

```
dStream foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val df = spark.read.json(rdd)
  // Need to join with the state somehow
  val unique = deduplicate(df)
  val result = myFancyProcessingMethod(unique)
  publish(result)
}
```

But now we've in the realm which has no notion of the stream (and, therefore, it's state), and I'm stuck.

The only solution I could think of is to dedupe the original DStream and only then convert it to DataFrames. That has several drawbacks: I have to parse the JSON twice, the algorithm itself could be implemented in DataFrames more efficiently (if it was a one-off task) etc. Is there any other way?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?